# Post Date Issues With MySQL

Tags: php, datetime, post

I am sending the date to the server in the following format: "01-01-1970"

I do this to get the date and format it:

```
$datetime =  date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($_POST["date"]  . "19:31:30"));
```

I then use PDO to send it to the database by simply doing:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO events
            (runnerID,eventDateTime,duration,
            cost,address,city,country,
            postcode,description) VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    ");
$stmt->execute(array($userID,$datetime,$_POST["duration"],$_POST["eventPrice"],
    $_POST["addressLine1"],$_POST["addressCity"],$_POST["addressCountry"],$_POST["addressPostCode"],$_POST["eventDesc"]));
```

But when I get to the database it saves as: "0000-00-00 00:00:00" the column is type "datetime"

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Can you show us the insert code?

Comment: Updated sorry, hope it helps

Comment: have you tried '$datetime' ?

Comment: I get "29-10-1992 19:31:30" when echoing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be date("Y-m-d H:i:s".....

```
$datetime =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST["date"]  . " 19:31:30"));
```

... and you have a missing space before the time

Comment: but as i said im getting the date in ""01-01-1970"

Comment: if your $_POST['date'] is in format d-m-Y that has nothing to do with the conversion. It is possible that it drives the strtotime crazy. Maybe you should change it to Y-m-d.

Comment: `if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.` So I guess your answer makes sense

Comment: When doinng that i get "1992-10-29 19:31:30" echoing but still all the zeros in the db

Answer (score 1):

With datetime fields you need to single quote your value '$datetime'.  This will populate your field.  I have made the same mistake a few times.

Comment: Do you mean single-quote(') instead of backtick (`)?

Answer (score 0):

try echoing the $datetime varible to see what you're getting prior to running the query.

Also you're posting unvalidated post values to the database which leaves you vulnerble to sql injection attacks. Validate each post value prior to running the query.

[filter input php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: When echoing i get "29-10-1992 19:31:30"

Comment: and thats definitly the wrong format for a mysql datetime field